# Typescript classes: Is explicit 'public' modifier a best-practice?

Tags: typescript

In TS, the default access level for a class member is `public` unless anything else is specified. Even so, is it considered a best-practice to use the `public` modifier anyway? If nothing else to make the code more obvious?

Comment: In my opinion it's best not to write it. It's less to maintain and it's less to look at. Additionally, not adding it makes protected and private members stand out more from public members so it's easy to quickly see what's what.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

This is a strongly subjective topic to which no perfect answer exists, IMO. However, I'd say a strong factor in settling on an answer is whether you are using other languages in parallel, and if there is a difference in default accessor modifiers between TypeScript and those other languages.

Take C#, for example. In C#, every property and field without an explicit access modifier is private. In TypeScript it's public, obviously.

If you happen to be using C# and TypeScript in the same project, or just in parallel, I would recommend going with explicit access modifiers, just for the sake of clarity.

Answer (score 36):

I personally, do like to list it every time. Of course it's just a matter of personal preference. If you do want to, and you use tslint, there is an option to force explicit visibility every time.

```
member-access: true
```

Comment: For those using modern typescript-eslint instead of tslint, the rule is: [`"@typescript-eslint/explicit-member-accessibility": "error"`](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/explicit-member-accessibility/)

Answer (score 4):

As other answers have stated, this is a matter of preference (I prefer the leaner version).

If you use [parameter properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#parameter-properties) though, the explicit `public` access modifier is *compulsory* in order to create and initialize an instance member from the given parameter.

```
class Octopus {
    readonly numberOfLegs: number = 8;
    constructor(public name: string, ink: boolean) { }
}

const o = new Octopus("Lui", true)
o.name // works
o.ink // error
```

Answer (score 1):

The upside to explicitly stating a public access modifier is that it shows you thought about it and that you decided that it should be public.
The downside is that extra syntax adds noise, which makes it harder for the important code to shine through (and it's more work for the developer to have to add that extra syntax every time).

I have seen a good few occasions where the private modifier should have been added but where access modifiers weren't taken into consideration.

To be honest, it would have been better if everything was private by default, and you would have to add `public` to open it up to the outside world.

Personally, I lean towards explicitly adding them.

However, I think for things that have to be public it's okay to use the default (since we don't have to think about whether it should be private or not, because it has to be public).

Examples (for Angular) are things like:
`@Input()`, `@Output()`, `@HostListener`, and implemented public methods.

Comment: Sorry but I disagree with "Extra noise". This is not exist in languages like C# and Java, you need say what the real visibility of the property, every time when you create one. 

Using the John Weisz's response, when you have ```Angular Project using Typescript and C# .NET core Back-end``` for example, I think better using strong types, because help to see what is private and public in both projects.

Preventing some erros or misinterpretation of the code.