# How to stop visual studio warning about presence of 'public' modifier

Tags: visual-studio, typescript

I have typescript class

```
class UserModel
{
    public vipTiers: Array<VipTierDto>;
    public games: Array<GameDto>;
}
```

This results in showing me this warning in VisualStudio 2015, TypeScript 2.0.6
**Your code style requires absence of 'public' modifiers**

Obviously I prefer to keep the private/public modifiers. Where can I set the coding style?

This is my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "sourceMap": true
  },
  "include": [
    "**/*.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Some good discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36943888/typescript-classes-is-explicit-public-modifier-a-best-practice) about best practices around this.

Answer (score 1):

I think this warning comes from ReSharper and not Visual Studio. If using ReSharper you can go to ReSharper --> Options --> TypeScript --> Code Style. Then check "Use explicit 'public' modifier". Works for me.

Comment: Thanks. Note in newer versions of VS it's **Extensions** --> Resharper --> ....