# When to write public keyword in typescript inside class?

Tags: typescript

As you know, all functions inside typescript class are public by default.

So when, in which circumstances i need to add 'public' keyword before function?

I ask because i never saw public keyword inside class, and i want to know what is the best practice here. Also we thought that for clarity the best practice is to write everywhere public and private keywords.

Thanks in ahead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript classes: Is explicit 'public' modifier a best-practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36943888/typescript-classes-is-explicit-public-modifier-a-best-practice)

Comment: @niiyeboah yes! Great! Thank you very much :)